# SharePoint patch insatallation

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, patching

I have not done any update or patch from 2016 till now .
IS Now i need to apply every patch month wise and year wise from 2016 to till date?
or only alone just latest CU 2020 update will remedies for previous all patch updates?

Below are few list i have pasted for your understanding.

Example :
Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update July 2016

Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update September 2017

Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update November 2018

Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update October 2018

Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update September 2017
Etc.....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You only need to install the latest cumulative update listed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/sharepoint-updates).

Because the update is "cumulative", the latest update contain all the previous update. As at the moment, 16.0.5071.1000 (October 2020) is the latest patch available to SharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install October 2020 update for SharePoint 2016.

Here's an article below about description of the security update for SharePoint enterprise server 2016: October 13, 2020. You could refer steps in the article to install update.

[SharePoint Server 2016 October 2020 update.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4486677/security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2016-october-13-2020)